# Rayleigh-Jeans Law

Tags: thermal-radiation

My question is simple, why do we believe [Rayleigh-Jeans law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Jeans_law) to be absurd? Is the Ultra-violet catastrophe incorrect or is it only because we can not create or know of a perfect emitter? I am a bit confused as to why Quanta was necessary.

Answer (score 7):

The Rayleigh-Jeans law states that the spectral radiance of a black body at temperature $T$ is given as
$$ B(\nu,T) = \frac{2k_B T}{c^2}\nu^2$$
The total radiance is then
$$ B_\text{tot}(T) = \int_0^\infty B(\nu,T)\mathrm{d}\nu$$
but the integral $\int_0^\infty x^2\mathrm{d}x$ does not converge. Worse, it is infinte, i.e. $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^k x^2\mathrm{d}x "=" \infty$.

Hence, the classically derived Rayleigh-Jeans law predicts that the radiance of a a blackbody is infinite. Since radiance is power per angle and unit area, this also implies that the total power and hence the energy a blackbody emitter gives off is infinite, which is patently absurd. This is called the [ultraviolet catastrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe) because the absurd prediction is caused by the classical law not predicting the behaviour at high frequencies/small wavelengths correctly.